# sqlalchemy always returning the same data

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLalchemy core (not sessions). I have a DB class that looks like this:

```
class DB(object):

    db_string = "mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (db_username, db_password, db_host, db_name)
    db_engine = create_engine(db_string, encoding="UTF-8", echo=False)
    db_conn = db_engine.connect()
    db_meta = MetaData()

    table1 = Table("table1", db_meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)

    def get_data(self, time_limit):
        stmt = select([self.table1]).where(self.table1.c.last_check < time_limit)
        return self.db_conn.execute(alexa_domains)
```

I instantiate this class once on load and pass the instance reference around. Now, the main program basically polls the DB in a loop to see if the time_limit is small enough to execute more code.

```
while 1:
    result = db_instance.get_data()
    check_if_result_has_data_smaller_than_time_limit(result) # THIS always returns False
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is that, if I change data in my database manually (the last_check field), or if another client make a change, this db_instance will apparently never see the new data and the size of result will always be 0. How can I prevent this behavior and make sure that on the next iteration it will see the new rows that should be returned?

Comment: if you have autocommit off, you're probably in a transaction and thus can't see any changes made outside of it.  you need to rollback before you do each check.  (also it's kinda weird to make the metadata and table attributes of a class.)

Comment: I'm not very clear on your comment. I did not change autocommit flag anywhere, I understood it as being default to True. Isn't rolling back part of ORM, and sessions? If so, I am not using them. Also why is it weird to make the metadata and table attributes of a class weird? I only want to load this code once and presumably my structure won't change much either. I thought that defining/loading the table every time I wanted to make a simple SELECT was overkill.

Comment: autocommit is also a mysql setting, but i don't know mysql well enough to guess where it might be set (possibly even in the db driver).  and no, rollback/commit are part of _using a database_, regardless of how you interact with it.  re making them class properties, i mean they generally exist at module level; you don't gain anything by putting them in a class instead.

Comment: ah I see, re: class properties, makes sense. It's more of a way to keep my settings organized (since I won't use those variables outside of the DB class). The reason I know something is wrong with SQLalchemy is that if I perform the same query from a different client (the cli, or another app) after modifying data, I get the fresh data, while querying with SQLalchemy always returns the same stale data set. It's as if I need to "reload" tables. In that sense I know that my changes are certainly "commited" since I can see them from another client.

Comment: @Eevee eventually found the answer - added it here. Thanks for your input.

Comment: that sounds basically like what i said  :)  the connection was in a transaction, so it never saw the other work you did.  when you throw away a connection, sqlalchemy automatically does a rollback on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was reusing the same connection. Here's the very simple fix:

```
class DB(object):

    db_string = "mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (db_username, db_password, db_host, db_name)
    db_engine = create_engine(db_string, encoding="UTF-8", echo=False)

    table1 = Table("table1", MetaData(), autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)

    def connect():
        return self.db_engine.connect()

    def get_data(self, time_limit):
        connection = self.connect()
        stmt = select([self.table1]).where(self.table1.c.last_check < time_limit)
        return connection.execute(alexa_domains)
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to force the autocommit in the selection instead of force a new connection.

```
 def get_data(self, time_limit):
     stmt = select([self.table1]).execution_options(autocommit=True).where(self.table1.c.last_check < time_limit)
     return connection.execute(alexa_domains)
```

see. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit